# How to copy some column to a new saved excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy some specific column from a source workbook to a new saved excel file by running a macro.

I have the following code:

```
Sub test_this()

    Dim sFileSaveName, cel, InitialName As String, column_name As String, NextColumn As Long
    
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDestin As Workbook
    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDestin As Worksheet, wsControl As Worksheet
    
    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Set wsControl = ActiveSheet                   
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")     
    
    InitialName = "Sample Output"
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    
    If sFileSaveName <> False Then

    End If

End Sub
```

Which can save the it as a new excel file, But how to get the path and open the source book, also copy the column that indicated in the active book and save it?

Here is my expected output

For example:
There are 4 columns: A, B, C and D in the source workbook
And here is my active workbook which run the vba.
If I put the column in the following order: D, A, C ,B in cell range B2:B5 and put the path of the source book in cell B6.
I should able to copy the the columns from source book, copy and save them as a new excel file. Column 1 would have D from source book. column 2 would have A....

Source Book: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZRrV.png

Active Book: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84B2f.png

New saved excel file : https://i.stack.imgur.com/U26hA.png

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub copy_column()
    Dim wbActive As Workbook, wbSource As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wsActive As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, nlstclm As Long
    Dim clm As Range
    
    Set wbActive = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsActive = wbActive.Sheets("Sheet1") 'rename to suit
    
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsActive.Range("B2:B5")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No column to copy."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("source.xlsx") 'rename to suit
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") 'rename to suit

    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    For Each clm In wsActive.Range("B2:B5")
        If clm <> Empty Then
            lastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, CStr(clm)).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngCopy = wsSource.Range(CStr(clm) & "2:" & CStr(clm) & lastRow)
            If wsNew.Cells(1, 1) = Empty Then
                nlstclm = wsNew.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Else
                nlstclm = wsNew.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            End If
            wsNew.Cells(1, nlstclm) = clm.Offset(0, -1)
            rngCopy.Copy wsNew.Cells(2, nlstclm)
        End If
    Next
    
    wbNew.SaveAs wsActive.Cells(6, 2) & "output.xlsx" 'rename to suit
    wbNew.Close False
    wbSource.Close False
    
    Set wbActive = Nothing
    Set wbSource = Nothing
    Set wbNew = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Copy completed."
End Sub
```